# SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, https

My site redirects a number of times before it lands. This issue occurred once the SSL certificate was implemented. Any ideas on how to fix this problem.

My site is posted with Vidahost - I asked them for help but they haven't a clue.

Unfortunately my programming skills a basic but if someone could point me in the right direction, I could probably solve it.

https://boconlineblog.co.uk

Many thanks in advance

```
# BEGIN Really_Simple_SSL_HSTS
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
</IfModule>
# END Really_Simple_SSL_HSTS
# BEGIN Really_Simple_SSL_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
</IfModule>
# END Really_Simple_SSL_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS

# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[2.5.26]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change your 'WordPress Address (URL)' and 'Site Address (URL)' to include the 'https' instead of the 'http' in your WordPress settings page under: **Settings -> General Settings**

If this doesn't fix it, then try getting it working with the 'Really Simple SSL' plugin: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

**Update**

After taking a look at your sites `.htaccess` file, I think the issue is being caused by the following lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} boconlineblog\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ boconlineblog.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

Try removing these lines and see if that fixes the issue.

**Update 2**

Try disabling the Really Simply SSL plugin and deleting everything from your `.htaccess` file except the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit`
```

Comment: Hi Mat, I've tried all those things yet it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you share your `.htaccess` code? And you don't have 'WP_HOME' or 'WP_SITEURL' defined anywhere in your `wp-config.php` file do you?

Comment: # BEGIN Really_Simple_SSL_HSTS
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
</IfModule>

Comment: # END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} boconlineblog\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://boconlineblog.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.

Comment: <IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

Comment: Hi - I don't have the following in wp_config : WP_HOME' or 'WP_SITEURL

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Please try that and let me know if that fixes.

Comment: No joy - :(  it's so frustrating

Comment: Can you add your full `.htaccess` code to your question by editing it and putting it in a code section? It's quite difficult to read it in comments.

Comment: I've added to the answers section is this correct - as I can't see a code section - sorry

Comment: Well I can see it now but you need to highlight the code and then click on the { } button in the toolbar to change it to a code block - please see screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/l0aMFv7

Comment: Sorry, just realised that you've added the code as an answer too. You can edit your question by clicking on 'edit', underneath your question...

Comment: I think I've done that now ? I hope that's correct

Comment: Yes, that's it ;-) However, I would recommend moving it to within your question by editing your question and then delete the answer you've posted as it will most likely get deleted by a moderator for not being an answer.

Comment: I've just updated my answer again. Try what I've suggested in **Update 2**

Comment: It is working now. It looks like it was a browser cache/cookie issue. I've just tested your site in another browser (Microsoft Edge) and the SSL is working fine now without redirects. Please check in another browser or clear your browser cache/cookies. Check the screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/m2XVMzG